# About the obstruction theory and homotopy?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, obstruction-theory

I am trying to read Hatcher's vector bundle and $K$-theory. I am trying to understand the obstruction theory in Chapter $3$.

When we get a vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow B$ and we may suppose that $B$ is $CW$ complex. We first suppose that $E$ is trivial on $B^1$, and we are tring to extend the $n$-sections over $B^2$. In Hatcher's original remark, we can get a map $\partial D^2\rightarrow SO(n)$ via characteristic map. (This is done by pulling bundle to $D^2$. this gets a trival bundle and we can restrict on the boundary $\partial D^2$, I think).

But here is the remark I cound't understand totally. This procedure defines an element $\pi_1(SO(n))$. By the definition of fundamental group, this expresses an equivalence classes of loops up to homotopy in $SO(n)$, but where does the homotopy come from ? (More generally, for the group $\pi_{n-k}(V_k(\mathbb R^n))$)

---

I think our goal is to extend the sections over $B^2$, just imagine a torus $T^2$, we've find a section over two circles ($1$-cell), and when we try to attach $2$-cell(a long "tube" with many circles I think) on the, when we find a new sections on the boundary, we can turn this around by $360$°. This procedure  describes what hatcher means $\partial D^2\rightarrow SO(n)$. ( This is just the special case of $V_{n-1}(\mathbb R^n)\cong SO(n)$ I guess).

But I still can't see why this defines a fundamental group ? Where does the homotopy comes from ?

Hope I've made my script clear. Appeciate your feedback!

Comment: Your language is confusing.  What is a "homotopic loop through $SO(n)$" - homotopic to *what*?

Comment: @JHF Can I express it as "equivalence classes of loops up to homotopy in $SO(n)$"? I just want to interpret the meaning of this fundamental group.

Comment: @jhf Maybe the intention is "homotopy class of loops..."

Comment: In that case, you don't need a homotopy to talk about the equivalence class containing a specifically given loop.